# How can I spawn an object on the opposite side of mesh(wall) I'm clicking on in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I'm using unity3d. So if I'm clicking on a mesh, for example a wall. I want to spawn an object on the opposite side of the wall I'm clicking on. It should work on x,y,& z axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply draw a vector from where you are to the wall `(wallPosition) - (YourPosition)`. `Normalizing` this vector will give you the `direction` you need to go to be on the other side of the wall. By knowing the direction then based on the thickness of the wall, its position, and ground position you can calculate the new position for your object.

Comment: But what if the wall is a part of a house and the whole house is a single object? How to place it just in the opposite side of wall instead of the whole house?

Comment: you can add a collider to your wall and Raycast from your position to where you click, this way you get a vector from your position to where you clicked